# Dynamically added elements are unable to dynamically added back to parent div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click

I'm having difficulty understanding why the dynamically (clicked) added elements from my 'Ingredients' div, to my 'Bought List' div, are NOT reacting the same way when clicked on the 'Bought' div, back to the 'Ingredients' div and repopulating it.

A snippet of the HTML used:

```
<div id="inner_bought_list"><br><br>
        <p>testing</p>
        <p>1 2 3</p>
</div> 

<div class= "content" id="ingred_checklist">
        <p>200g thin dried rice-stick noodles</p>
        <p>185g Ayam Malaysian laksa paste </p>
        <p>1/2 small red onion, quartered, thinly sliced</p>
```

This code here successfully and dynamically adds the text of the p-tag elements from my 'Ingredients' div to my 'Bought' div, whilst also removing them from the 'Ingredients' div (the console reflects this):

```
$('#ingred_checklist p').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $(this).text();
        console.log(toAdd);

        var string = '<p>' + '•' + toAdd + '</p>';
        console.log(string);

        var tAS = $('#inner_bought_list').append(string);
        console.log(tAS);

    });

    $(document).on('click', '#ingred_checklist p', function() {
        $(this).remove();

    });
```

However, when I try to click the items in 'Bought' div, that were dynamically added via the .on('click') from 'Ingredients', they are successfully removed from the 'Bought' div, but not added (back) to the 'Ingredients' div. The console also does NOT show that that when the dynamically added p-tags are clicked, storing of the .text() into 'var toAddRet'.

```
$('#inner_bought_list p').click(function() {
    var toAddRet = $(this).text();
    console.log(toAddRet);

    var stringRet = '<p>' + toAddRet + '</p>';
    console.log(stringRet);

    var tASRet= $('#ingred_checklist').append(stringRet);
    console.log(tASRet);

});

    $(document).on('click', '#inner_bought_list p', function() {
    $(this).remove();

});
```

Essentially, the p-tags that initially present in the html are able to be added to the other div, but not the dynamically added ones.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delegate your events:

```
$('body')on('click', '#ingred_checklist p', function() {

   var toAdd = $(this).text();
    console.log(toAdd);

    var string = '<p>' + '•' + toAdd + '</p>';
    console.log(string);

    var tAS = $('#inner_bought_list').append(string);
    console.log(tAS);

});


$('body')on('click', '#inner_bought_list p', function() {
    var toAddRet = $(this).text();
    console.log(toAddRet);

    var stringRet = '<p>' + toAddRet + '</p>';
    console.log(stringRet);

    var tASRet= $('#ingred_checklist').append(stringRet);
    console.log(tASRet);

});
```

Otherwise, newly appended elements won't have the event bound. By delegating, the event is bound to a parent container that will propagate the event to the given children. For performance, you should delegate the event from the closest static parent (I've used the body for the sake of the example).